# Handle 'paste' event on parent element only event target has no default paste action

Tags: javascript, html

I have:

1. html grid, that might contain cell with text inputs.
2. custom paste functionality (e.g. paste entire rows), that I want to invoke when user pastes something to the grid, but only when the event target doesn't have default paste functionality (e.g. inputs, textareas, etc)

Consider following snippet, that show alert, when user pastes somting:

```js
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");

grid.addEventListener("paste", (event) => {
    alert('Grid custom paste');
});
```

```html
<div class="grid" contenteditable="true">
   <div class="row" tabindex="1">
     <div class="cell" tabindex="1">Cell A</div>
     <div class="cell" tabindex="1"><input value="CellB"/></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I only want to show the alert, when user pastes something to CellA, not to the input CellB.

How can I find out, that the event target has some default paste action?

Comment: *"How can I find out, that the event target has some default paste action?"* The whole thing is content-editable, so what default paste action does CellB have that CellA doesn't have? Are you just looking to determine whether the target is a form field?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");

grid.addEventListener("paste", (event) => {
  const target = event.target;
  if (
    (target.tagName === "DIV" && target.hasAttribute("contenteditable")) ||
    (target.tagName !== "INPUT" && target.tagName !== "TEXTAREA")
  ) {
    alert('Grid custom paste');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="grid" contenteditable="true">
  <div class="row" tabindex="1">
    <div class="cell" tabindex="1">Cell A</div>
    <div class="cell" tabindex="1"><input value="CellB"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

add this condition to solve your problem

```js
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");

grid.addEventListener("paste", (event) => {
  const target = event.target;
  if (
    target.tagName !== "INPUT" &&
    target.tagName !== "TEXTAREA" &&
    !target.hasAttribute("contenteditable")
  ) {
    alert('Grid custom paste');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="grid" contenteditable="true">
  <div class="row" tabindex="1">
    <div class="cell" tabindex="1">Cell A</div>
    <div class="cell" tabindex="1"><input value="CellB"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `contenteditable` applies to descendant elements, so just that check won't be sufficient. And both `CellA` and `CellB` are inside a content-editable element. You might be on the right track with the check for whether the paste occurs in a text field (though not an `input` elements are text fields).

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score -1):

You may try the following:

```
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid div.row div.cell:first-child");
grid.addEventListener("paste", (event) => {
   alert('Grid custom paste');
});
```

Comment: Not downvoted by me, but this solution only works in this extremly simplified demo. Of course it is easy to attach evenlistener to particular cell, but I'm looking for much more generic approach